# How to get specific string from the given string without regex in python?

Tags: python, string, list

I have strings like:

```
s1 = "select_12_164_Saudi_Arabia_279976"
s2 = "select_10_164_Afric__MiddleEast_87821"
```

I want to just getting only country or continent name but without regex and without any importing lib?

I want this:

```
s1 = "Saudi_Arabia"
s2 = "Afric__MiddleEast"
```

is it possible without regex?

*Note: "Afric__MiddleEast" contains two underscore.*

Comment: What do you know to be constant? Why are there 2 underscores? What identifies countries with one word from those with only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
>>> '_'.join(s1.split('_')[3:-1])
'Saudi_Arabia'

>>> '_'.join(s2.split('_')[3:-1])
'Afric__MiddleEast'
```